# Errors occurs while the final step of gcc make

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, building

I build gcc for arm from scratch. In the final step of building gcc occur errors. I'm counting on your help.

```
bogdan@bogdan-VirtualBox:~/xtools/build2/final-gcc-2$ $gcc_src/configure --build=$buildmach --host=$targetmach --target=$targetmach --prefix=$installdir --with-sysroot=$sysrootdir --enable-languages=c --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-multilib --with-float=soft --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --enable-long-longx --with-shared --with-gmp=$installdir --with-mpfr=$installdir --without-isl
```

**make**

```
a lot of log
checking how to run the C preprocessor... (cached) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... (cached) /bin/grep
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for memory.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for minix/config.h... (cached) no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... (cached) yes
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... (cached) no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... (cached) 64
checking whether arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -Wall... (cached) yes
checking for -static-libgcc... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... (cached) /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld
checking if the linker (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld) is GNU ld... (cached) yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... (cached) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm
checking the name lister (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm) interface... (cached) BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... (cached) 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld option to reload object files... (cached) -r
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump... (cached) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... (cached) pass_all
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar... (cached) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip... (cached) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib... (cached) arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
checking command to parse arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm output from arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc object... (cached) ok
checking for dlfcn.h... (cached) yes
checking for objdir... (cached) .libs
checking if arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... (cached) no
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... (cached) yes
checking if arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc static flag -static works... (cached) yes
checking if arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking if arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc linker (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... (cached) no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for int64_t... (cached) yes
checking for uint64_t... (cached) yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... (cached) yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
make[2]: вход в каталог «/home/bogdan/xtools/build2/final-gcc-2/lto-plugin»
make  all-am
make[3]: вход в каталог «/home/bogdan/xtools/build2/final-gcc-2/lto-plugin»
WARNING: liblto_plugin.la is static, not copying to ../gcc/liblto_plugin.la
make[3]: выход из каталога «/home/bogdan/xtools/build2/final-gcc-2/lto-plugin»
make[2]: выход из каталога «/home/bogdan/xtools/build2/final-gcc-2/lto-plugin»
Configuring in ./gcc
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-none-linux-gnueabi
checking target system type... arm-none-linux-gnueabi
checking LIBRARY_PATH variable... ok
checking GCC_EXEC_PREFIX variable... ok
checking whether to place generated files in the source directory... no
checking whether a default linker was specified... no
checking whether a default assembler was specified... no
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gnatbind... no
checking for arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... no
checking for memory.h... no
checking for strings.h... no
checking for inttypes.h... no
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for unistd.h... no
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E
checking for inline... inline
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... unknown
checking for _LARGE_FILES value needed for large files... unknown
checking size of void *... 0
checking size of short... 0
checking size of int... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking for long long... no
checking for int8_t... no
checking for int16_t... no
checking for int32_t... no
checking for int64_t... no
checking for long long int... no
checking for intmax_t... no
checking for intptr_t... no
checking for uint8_t... no
checking for uint16_t... no
checking for uint32_t... no
checking for uint64_t... no
checking for unsigned long long int... no
checking for uintmax_t... no
checking for uintptr_t... no
configure: error: uint64_t or int64_t not found
Makefile:4200: recipe for target 'configure-gcc' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-gcc] Error 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/bogdan/xtools/build2/final-gcc-2»
Makefile:891: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Update

Solution: 
bogdan@bogdan-VirtualBox:~/xtools/build2/final-gcc-2$ $gcc_src/configure --build=$buildmach --target=$targetmach --prefix=$installdir CC=gcc --with-sysroot=$sysrootdir --enable-languages=c --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-multilib --with-float=soft --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --enable-long-longx --with-shared --with-gmp=$installdir --with-mpfr=$installdir

With that another errors appeared:

```
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... /home/bogdan/xtools/arm/sysroot
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-mt... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... no
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking whether gcc __attribute__ ((mode (XX))) works... yes
checking for recent GMP... yes
checking usable gmp.h at link time... yes
checking for GMP_NUMB_BITS and sizeof(mp_limb_t) consistency... no
configure: error: GMP_NUMB_BITS and sizeof(mp_limb_t) are not consistent.
You probably need to change some of the GMP or MPFR compile options.
See 'config.log' for details (search for GMP_NUMB_BITS).
Makefile:5126: recipe for target 'configure-mpfr' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-mpfr] Error 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/bogdan/xtools/build/final-gcc»
Makefile:891: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: it is an error during _configure_, you have none of the `<signed unsigned int>_t` nor `long long` with your _gcc_

Comment: `checking for ANSI C header files... no` ... `checking for stdlib.h... no` ... How did you get _gcc_ ? Perhaps you have some change to do in the _configure_ files to change a directory or something like ?

Comment: I downloaded gcc from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/. I will check configure files but the previous steps of making gcc was successful such as '$gcc_src/configure --build=$buildmach --target=$targetmach CC=gcc --prefix=$installdir --with-sysroot=$sysrootdir --enable-languages=c --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-multilib --with-float=soft --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --enable-long-longx' 'make all-gcc' 'make install-gcc'

Comment: I think the first steps check your already present compiler, and there are ok, and the second part check the validity of the compiler and its files you compile, no ?

Comment: Why ...checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes ... and then ...checking for ANSI C header files... no...?

Comment: "configure: loading cache ./config.cache", probably you did several attempts and may be some not being in the right condition. Delete **all** the files _config.cache_ to let the configure doing its job, use _find_ or equiv to be sure to find all of them, then redo the build.

Comment: I see, thank you for answering! I have another questions. What does this means (cached)? What is the differences between, for example, checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes and checking for ANSI C header files... no? According to tutorial i did echo "libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes" > config.cache and echo "libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes" >> config.cache before the gcc's configure but i don't understand why that's need? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: _cached_ means the value come from _config.cache_ rather than to be computed/established again. When you run _configure_ the first time all is computed and that can need time, if you redo later _configure_ (without removing the _config.cache_ file) it reuse the results it got previously, that accelerates the process

Comment: I think, i understood what was wrong. If i will right, i will add the answer and will close the question.

Comment: I solved my error by removing --host and adding CC=gcc in /configure. But another errors appeared. I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: `bogdan@bogdan-VirtualBox:~/xtools/build2/final-gcc-2$ $gcc_src/configure --build=$buildmach --target=$targetmach --prefix=$installdir CC=gcc --with-sysroot=$sysrootdir --enable-languages=c --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-multilib --with-float=soft --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --enable-long-longx --with-shared --with-gmp=$installdir --with-mpfr=$installdir`